# linux device drivers: unable to get data in loff_t parameter

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am trying to read from driver. But loff_t parameter does not receive in kernel space.

kernel object code:

```
 static ssize_t cg_FRAM_read(struct file *filep, unsigned char *buffer, size_t addr, loff_t *off); //declaration

static ssize_t cg_FRAM_read(struct file *filep, unsigned char *buffer, size_t addr, loff_t *off)
{
printk("addr=%x,count=%x %x %x",addr,*off,off);
return 0;
}
```

call to function from user space c code:

```
count=10;
p_loc=20;
read(fd_FRAM,&buffer[0],count,&p_loc);
```

now problem is when read is executed i can receive all data upto variable addr in driver but i am not able to receive data in *off.
printk output  show *off=0 and off=0;

Comment: Have you implemented your own syscall called read and deleted the one which is already implemented ? refer this http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html

Comment: a) Your printk has a mismatched number of %'s and arguments, b) your user space read has the wrong number of arguments (see read(2)), c) what makes you think 0 is wrong, your read function never returns any data, so an offset of 0 would be expected.

Comment: Please provide full, yet minimal examples. Buildable examples.